# When using MEW to deploy a contrct the gas limit goes to -1 when I paste in the bytecode

Tags: contract-development, contract-deployment, gas, metamask, myetherwallet

The gas limit that should set automatically to an estimate just goes to -1 and when I change it manually to the max allowed integer the transaction still fails to deploy the contract (and the gas is consumed).

Anyone know what I can do to fix this?

Comment: I didn't know that you can deploy a contract in myetherwallet. Found this article on Medium, you might want to have a look.https://medium.com/@prashantprabhakarsingh/deploying-contract-using-bytecode-myetherwallet-and-remix-10f643a82d40

Comment: Thanks Geeroz. I had read that. I actually got a simple contract to deploy once before using a test net (can't remember if it was rinkeby or ropsten) and MEW with Metamask.

Comment: Are you sure the bytecode is correct? How did you produce such bytecode? Did you try deploying first to a local testnet? ie using ganache for example.

Comment: Hi, The bytecode is retrieved from compiling in Remix and clicking the "details" of the contract.